# Java Object Creation Error

Tags: java, object, creation

```
package Sartre.Connect4;

import javax.swing.*;


public class ChatGUI extends JDialog {

public ChatGUI(){

    setTitle("Chat");

}
```

}

when i do this in another class in the same package:

```
ChatGUI chatGUI = new ChatGUI();
```

i end up with a situation: Cannot Find Symbol

please help?

Comment: Could you post the code for your other class?

Comment: that is all theres to it. rest of of the main class is unrelated to ChatGUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are both files in the directory

```
<project root>/Sartre/Connect4 ?
```

It might mess things up if the structure is

```
<project root>/Sarte.Connect4
```

Comment: i think it is something to do with this. i made a copy of this to another folder and using the copy.

Answer (score 3):

"Cannot Find Symbol" means that the compiler cannot find a class, method or field that's being used in your code (it wil also tell you exactly which one). This means one of two things:

- The class/method/field name is mistyped
- The compiler cannot find it in its classpath